# Create events in React Big Calendar

Tags: reactjs, calendar

I'm trying to create events in  [react-big-calendar](https://github.com/intljusticemission/react-big-calendar) by dragging, putting the data in a Tootip form and send a request to server to save it. 
Problem after i drag the event the selection disappears: i need it to stay until I submit the event. Right now 
[it works like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOCjp.png)

In the docs/examples they have alert, which of corse stops exection of function and the selection remains the same:

```
 <BigCalendar
      selectable
      events={events}
      defaultView='week'
      scrollToTime={new Date(1970, 1, 1, 6)}
      defaultDate={new Date(2015, 3, 12)}
      onSelectEvent={event => alert(event.title)}
      onSelectSlot={(slotInfo) => alert(
        `selected slot: \n\nstart ${slotInfo.start.toLocaleString()} ` +
        `\nend: ${slotInfo.end.toLocaleString()}`
      )}
    />
```

if i trow and error at the end of onSelectSlot function it stays also open the selection, but then i need to close after I submit.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `onSelecting` method for dragging a selection this will give you an object with start and end date of the selection `{ start: Date, end: Date }` and make sure to not return false on this method, for more information see the documentation [here](http://intljusticemission.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html#prop-onSelecting)